# Undefined variable: user in view on line 60 NULL Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm trying to pass an array in `redirect` to another page but it say undefined variable `user`

```
return $this->response->redirect($this->MyHelper->Route('eb-user-verify-reset-password-code'), $User->toArray());
```

How can I access `$user->toArray()` in the redirected page?

I try to recive it like `<?php var_dump($user);?>` in my new page but it's throwing the below error:

> Undefined variable: user in view on line 60 NULL Phalcon

**Details:**

I'm passing **user** details via redirect function to another page. So in the redirect I'm passing the user details as second param. But I'm getting error in the page where I want to receive the user details array.

Comment: Maybe u need to use query string or save into session for next page

Comment: @devpro yes session is a good option, but i was wondering if it was possible via redirect func!

Answer (score 0):

`Phalcon\Http\Response::redirect()` will redirect using http and you can't pass any data unless using POST, GET, etc

if you asking for another way to redirect with parameters you can use `Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher::forward()`

example:

```php
$this->dispatcher->forward(
    [
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'search',
        'params' => [1, 2, 3]
    ]
);
```

refer to the documentation for more info https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/dispatcher#forwarding

Comment: So we can't pass a variable in `redirect` func?

Comment: you can using get which is would be public to the client
example:
```http://www.somedomain/phalcon/?somevar=somevalue```
please read the documentation https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/response#redirections